# Consulta SQL (PostgreSQL) seleccionar filas donde coincidan dos columnas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito una consulta SQL donde obtener todas las filas de la tabla 1 donde coincidan valores de pares de la tabla 2, ejemplo:

Tabla 1 (respuestas)

```
| id | Usuario |
| 12 |   Juan  |
| 23 |   Pedro |
```

Tabla 2 (respuesta_valores)

```
ID | respuesta_id | pregunta_id  | valor |
1  |  12          | 1            | SI
2  |  12          | 2            | NO
3  |  23          | 1            | NO
4  |  23          | 2            | SI
```

Necesito que dado los pares de valores

```
pregunta_id = 1 y valor = 'SI'
pregunta_id = 2 y valor = 'NO'
```

la consulta devuelva la fila con ID 1 de la tabla 1

la siguiente consulta me devuelve cero resultados:

```
select count(*) 
       from respuestas 
       join respuesta_valores 
            ON respuestas.id = respuesta_valores.respuesta_id 
       where (pregunta_id = 528 AND valor = 'SI') 
             AND (pregunta_id = 527 AND valor = 'NO');
```

Si lo hacemos con OR funciona, pero devuelve más resultados de lo esperado.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, habría que ver que `respuesta_id` tiene las dos condiciones dadas:

```
SELECT respuesta_id
       FROM respuesta_valores 
       WHERE (pregunta_id = 528 AND valor = 'SI') 
             OR (pregunta_id = 527 AND valor = 'NO');
       GROUP BY respuesta_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

El `where` nos retornará dos filas si se dan las condciones esperadas, luego mediante el `having` solo filtramos aquellas `respuesta_id` que tengan las dos condiciones esperadas

Luego simplemente puedes integrar esta consulta para obtener las filas de `respuestas`:

```
SELECT *
       FROM respuestas
       WHERE id in ( SELECT respuesta_id
                             FROM respuesta_valores 
                             WHERE (pregunta_id = 528 AND valor = 'SI') 
                                  OR (pregunta_id = 527 AND valor = 'NO');
                            GROUP BY respuesta_id
                            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de resolverlo:

Puedes transponer la preguntas como columnas de manera que te queden todas en una sola fila (una fila por persona con los valores de cada una de la preguntas), lo que se conoce como pivot table. Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT respuesta_id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN pregunta_id = 1 THEN valor END) AS pregunta_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN pregunta_id = 2 THEN valor END) AS pregunta_2
FROM respuesta_valores
GROUP BY respuesta_id
```

El resultado sería:

| respuesta_id | pregunta_1 | pregunta_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | SI | NO |
| 23 | NO | SI |

La query que vos querés utilizando la subquery anterior sería:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM respuestas r
INNER JOIN (SELECT respuesta_id,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN pregunta_id = 1 THEN valor END) AS pregunta_1,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN pregunta_id = 2 THEN valor END) AS pregunta_2
            FROM respuesta_valores
            GROUP BY respuesta_id) AS rv ON r.id = rv.respuesta_id
WHERE pregunta_1 = 'SI' AND pregunta_2 = 'NO';
```